# Write after end error when launch server in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am beginner at NodeJS and I'm doing a "NodeJS and Express.js full course" at freecodecamp yt and I copied author code which for him works perfectly, but I got an error.

Code:

```
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=> {
if(req.url === '/') {
    res.end('Home Page')
}
if(req.url === '/about') {
   res.end('About us')
}
res.end('Error')
})

server.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('Server listening...');
})
```

I don't know why he got home, about and error page when user goes to the wrong page it should throw "Error" text on page, but instead my program is throwing an error in nodeJS program:

```
events.js:377
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:694:15)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:815:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\nodejs\app.js:10:5)
    at Server.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:900:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:127:17)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:753:7) 
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

Can someone explain this to me? I would be appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might also want to add `return` before `res end()` otherwise the last `res.end()` will excute when url is `/` and `/about` and will throw error.

Comment: It worked out. I added return before every res.end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s caused by the `res.end('Error')`, which gets always executed. Try to put it into an `else` clause, or put a `return` before each `res.end(…)`

Comment: Works even without else.
I added return before every res.end. Thanks!